# Higher-order, nonlinear differential equation with Initial Values

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I tried to solve for an non-Hookean spring's motion, but the output from *Mathematica* is weird. It seems that there is inverse functions involved.

```
DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0}, x[t], t]
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
Out[1] = {{x[t] -> -I 2^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] Sqrt[C[1]]
 JacobiSN[Sqrt[
 Sqrt[2] t^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2]/Sqrt[2], -1]}, {x[t] -> I 2^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] Sqrt[C[1]] JacobiSN[Sqrt[Sqrt[2] t^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2]/Sqrt[2], -1]}}
```

If you try `Reduce`, *Mathematica* will then give you no output at all, which makes sense because the output is not an equality or inequality.

Also, I added initial values into `DSolve`, but I'm unable to obtain the answer.

```
In[1]:= DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0, x[0] == d, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions. >>
DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions. >>
Out[1]= {}
```

Comment: Welcome to MathematicaSE. Please add your *Mathematic* code instead of screen shots, use the `{ }` of the editor to input code and the Image button do add images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that was easy:

```
Block[{Simplify = FullSimplify},
  DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == x0}, x[t], t]
  ] // FullSimplify
(*
  {{x[t] -> x0 JacobiCD[(t x0)/Sqrt[2], -1]}}
*)
```

`DSolve` uses `Simplify` to check the solution, and `Simplify` is not up to the task.  So I used `Block` to replace it with `FullSimplify`, which will reduce the DE to `True` after `DSolve` substitutes the solution.  Perhaps the `Method` option could be used, but there are no clues to how to use it.

Comment: Wow, dude! You're awesome!

Comment: Hey Michael, your answer is concise and super helpful. However, I still don't understand how it works. For example, why does `FullSimplify[DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == x0}, x[t], t]]` doesn't work? What's special about the `Block[]` command? What is the mechanism of `Block[{Simplify = FullSimplify, expr]`?

Comment: `Block` is a way to give a symbol a local definition that applies only within the `Block`.  Inside the block, any call to `Simplify` actually calls `FullSimplify`, even **inside** the `DSolve` code, which is where it is needed.  Calling `FullSimplify` outside of `DSolve` only simplifies the result (which I also did).  Look it up in Help or see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559).

Comment: Then here comes my question. How did you know that the `Simplify` is called **inside** the `DSolve` function and that by using `FullSimplify` instead we can solve the problem? Is it shown in the documentation center of Mathematica?

Comment: @GeorgeZhang In some sense luck: `foo = Trace[DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0, x[0] == d, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t], TraceInternal -> True]`.  Now `DSolve` uses `Integrate` (of course, maybe), so look for `Integrate` in the 7GB of output by mapping `FreeQ[Integrate]` over parts of `foo`.  Try this: `NestWhile[Extract[#, Last@Position[FreeQ[Integrate] /@ #, False]] &, foo, ListQ]`. (Not exactly how I did it, but hindsight is golden.) When I saw the answer to DE, I then just had to hunt down where it was rejected (in the same way with `FreeQ`).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving screenshots you should copy your code and paste to this section properly. Ok, now I give a general approach to solve this problem.

```
In[1]:= DSolve[x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[t], t]

Out[1]= {{x[t] -> C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]}}
```

Well, Mathematica does the job well and easy. Your problem shouldn't be that hard. Let's see:

```
In[2]:= eqn = x''[t] == -x[t]^3; sol = DSolve[eqn, x, t]

During evaluation of In[2]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Out[2]= {{x -> 
   Function[{t}, -I 2^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] Sqrt[C[1]]
      JacobiSN[Sqrt[
      Sqrt[2] t^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2]/Sqrt[2], -1]]}, {x -> 
   Function[{t}, 
    I 2^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] Sqrt[C[1]]
      JacobiSN[Sqrt[
      Sqrt[2] t^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2]/Sqrt[2], -1]]}}
```

What happened? I wanted an easy output! Ok, actually, this type of DE does not explicitly depend on `t` or `x'[t]`. In order to reduce this equation to first order ODE with independent var `x`, Mathematica needs (and uses) inverse functions. You see `JacobiSN` at `Out[2]` which is the inverse of `EllipticK`. Solve uses `JacobiSN` to find an expression for `x[t]`. Here is the plot of the solutions:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  x[t] /. {sol[[1]], sol[[2]]} /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}], {t, -5, 
  5},
 AxesLabel -> {"time", "displacement"},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

You can change the coefficients `C[1]` and `C[2]`, and see the resulting plots.

Comment: This is super helpful! However, I still don't know what should I do if I want to solve for solution with initial values because if I just include IVs in DSolve command, Mathematica just simply refuses to do it.

Comment: Also, I tried your solution and find the `Evaluation[]` command really makes a difference. If I don't include it in my plot command, like `Plot[x[t] /. {sol[[1]], sol[[2]]} /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}, {t, -5, 
  5}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "displacement"}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`, the graph I get is not correctly filled.  <br/>But, when I computed `Evaluate[x[t] /. {sol[[1]], sol[[2]]} /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}]` and `x[t] /. {sol[[1]], sol[[2]]} /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 3}`, there is no different between the output of these two commands. I'm confused. Could you explain why the `Evaluate` matters?

Comment: The list `x[t]` in has attribute `HoldAll`. `Plot` evaluates the `Table` separately. As you saw when you tried the `Plot` command without `Evaluate`, the two functions of `x[t]` are treated as one function and thus they have same colours and the are between them is not filled.

Answer (score 2):

Higher-order, nonlinear differential equation are usually difficult.  We can solve the general equation and try to solve the initial condition for the constants of integration.

```
sol = DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == 0}, x, t];
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

If the initial condition is `x[0] == x0, x'[0] == p0`, then these determine the first two coefficients of the Taylor series.  So let's get the first two Taylor coefficients in three steps: First the coefficients of the series, which turn out to have simplifications that `Simplify` does not perform by default.  Second, take the `-1`s out of the powers, which will cancel out the `I`s.  Finally replace the constants of integration by simpler parameters.

```
ivterms = Simplify[CoefficientList[Normal@Series[
     x[t] /. First[sol],
     {t, 0, 1}],
   t],
  {C[1], C[2]} ∈ Reals];
ivterms = ivterms /. Power[Times[-1, e__], n_] :> I^(2 n) Power[Times[e]];
  (* Inverse replacement: {c1 -> C[1]C[2]^4, c2 -> C[2]} *)
ivterms = 
 ivterms /. {Power[C[1], n_] :> c1^n/Abs[C[2]]^(4 n)} /. {Power[
     Abs[C[2]], n_?EvenQ] -> c2^n, C[2] -> c2}
(*
  {(2^(1/4) c2^2 JacobiSN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1])/Sqrt[c1], 
   (c1^(3/4) JacobiCN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1] JacobiDN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1])/c2^3}
*)
```

Solve the initial condition:  First case, `p0 = 0`.

```
Solve[First@ivterms == x0, {c2}]
Solve[Last@ivterms == 0 /. #, {c1}] & /@ %
(*
  {{c2 -> -((c1^(1/4) Sqrt[x0])/(2^(1/8) Sqrt[JacobiSN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1]]))},
   {c2 -> (c1^(1/4) Sqrt[x0])/(2^(1/8) Sqrt[JacobiSN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1]])}}
*)
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*
  {{{c1 -> 0}, {c1 -> 2 EllipticK[-1]^4}}, {{c1 -> 0}, {c1 ->  2 EllipticK[-1]^4}}}
*)
```

Second case: generic `p0`.  Unfortunately, we can't solve exactly for `c1`.

```
Solve[First@ivterms == x0, {c2}]
Solve[Last@ivterms == p0, {c1}]
(*
  {{c2 -> -((c1^(1/4) Sqrt[x0])/(2^(1/8) Sqrt[JacobiSN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1]]))},
   {c2 -> (c1^(1/4) Sqrt[x0])/(2^(1/8) Sqrt[JacobiSN[c1^(1/4)/2^(1/4), -1]])}}
*)
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

So one is left with using `FindRoot` to numerically solve for `c1` for a given numerical initial condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, if I use Maple to solve this IV problem, I can just include the IVs in my "dsolve" command and get answer right after execution. The fail of Mathematica in this case is very likely due to its rigorousness. But if it can be done in Maple in one step, I just want to know if there is easier way in Mathematica than tons of code and manual manipulation.

Comment: @GeorgeZhang Does the new answer do what you desire?

Comment: Yeah, the new one is exactly what I want! Guys, thanks for your help!