# Analytic approximation of NDSOLVE

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve the following differential equation

```
L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - 0.1
```

I tried DSolve:

```
Clear[t]
Clear[L]
Clear[solution]
solution = DSolve[{L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - 0.1, L[0] == 10}, L[t], t]
```

which did not work. Now NDSolve gives me a good result:

```
Clear[t]
Clear[L]
Clear[solution]
extf = 0.1
tmax = 10000
solution = NDSolve[{L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - extf, 
            L[0] == 10}, L[t], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[L[t] /. solution], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

How can I approximate this function through an analytic representation (fitting)? If thats not possible: How to export the InterpolatedFunction as a data file?

Thank you all!

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64481/how-to-solve-arcsinh-equation-for-many-differents-parameters/64529#64529), under "Making Tables", for exporting interpolating functions.  Also look up `FindFit` and its relatives for the first part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why `DSolve` fails, but the differential equation can be solved in the usual way of separating the variables.*  So `t` will be equal to

```
solt = Integrate[1/(LL^(-3/2) - 1/10), {LL, 10, L}, Assumptions -> 10^(2/3) < L < 10];
(* complicated output omitted - see below *)
```

We can use `InverseFunction` to get `L` in terms of `t`:

```
solL = L -> InverseFunction[Evaluate[solt] & /. L -> #]
(*
  L -> InverseFunction[-(10/3) (-30 + 3 #1 - 
      2 Sqrt[3] 10^(2/3) ArcTan[(1 + 2 10^(1/6))/Sqrt[3]] + 
      2 Sqrt[3] 10^(2/3)ArcTan[(5 + 10^(2/3) Sqrt[#1])/(5 Sqrt[3])] - 
      10^(2/3) Log[10] - 2 10^(2/3) Log[-1 + 10^(1/6)] + 
      10^(2/3) Log[1 + 10^(1/6) + 10^(1/3)] + 
      2 10^(2/3) Log[-10 + 10^(2/3) Sqrt[#1]] - 
      10^(2/3) Log[10 + 10^(2/3) Sqrt[#1] + 10^(1/3) #1]) &]
*)
```

Check:

```
{L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - 1/10, L[0] == 10} /. solL // FullSimplify
(*  {True, True}  *)
```

You might want to stick with the `NDSolve` solution.  This one is very difficult to evaluate (yes, that's fifteen seconds for one value):

```
N[L[450] /. solL] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {15.478482, 4.6416}  *)
```

---

*Update in response to comment:  A standard solution to an initial value problem of the form
$$ {dL\over dt} = {f(L)\over g(t)}, \quad L(t_0)=L_0$$
is given by
$$ \int_{L_0}^L {dL' \over f(L')} = \int_{t_0}^t {dt' \over g(t')} $$
In the example IVP given in the question $f(L)$ is `L[t]^(-3/2) - 1/10`, $g(t)$ is `1`, $L_0$ is `10`, and $t_0 = 0$.  These parameters have to be adapted to each IVP.  The `Integrate` code above use `Assumptions` to get a simplified form of the integral as well as the right branch.  In general a critical value where $f(L) = 0$ is a singular value of the integral.  These can cause trouble for `Integrate` in the sense that it might (and sometimes does) generate conditions that are more restrictive than necessary

Comment: Your L is less than 10 since the derivative at t=0 is negative.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick Yes, I know. We have $10^{2/3} < L \le 10$ for $t \ge 0$. (I'm not sure why you made the comment.)

Comment: Sorry, was a bit brief! I think there are two things here. One is that you use assumtion that L is larger than 10 when solving for the integral. Yes, and I thought that another was that something might start happening to L once it gets to zero. But evidently it doesn't reach zero.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick Ah, thanks.  Fixed now.  And yes it doesn't reach zero because there an equilibrium position where `L0^(-3/2) - 1/10 == 0`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Cheers!

Comment: Why exactly do you set the range for L? With NDSolve I found a solution (different constants) where the derivative is always >0 so that `L>10` for `t>0` which is exactly what I am interested in. OK maybe should have specified that. Sorry

Comment: @user3683367 You specified `L[0] == 10` in your code.  It follows that `L[t]` will be less than 10 for `t > 0`.  The use of `Assumptions` was to simplify the result. `Integrate` will return a complex-valued antiderivative with no assumptions, and a `ConditionalExpression` if we tell `Integrate` that `L` lies in an interval containing `10` and the integral starts at `L = 10`.  Note you get the same integral whether we specify `L > 10` or `10^(2/3) < L < 10` in `Assumptions`.  If the initial condition for `L[0]` is some number `ic`, then the integral should be over `{L0, ic, L}`.

Comment: @user3683367 You must have changed the differential equation to get a solution for which `L[t] > 10` remains true.  The (real) solutions to `L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - 0.1` all converge to `10^(2/3)`.  I'm guessing you're dealing with `L'[t] == L[t]^(-3/2) - a` for various values of `a`.  Then `a^(-2/3)` will be the critical value.  BTW, with exact solvers such as `DSolve` and `Integrate`, and sometimes with numeric solvers that do symbolic analysis, exact input usually gives better results (e.g., use `1/10` instead of `0.1`).

Comment: note you can use the indefinite integral to get a generic solution without making the assumptions: `FullSimplify[# - (# /. L -> L0)] &@ Integrate[1/(L^(-3/2) - c), L]`.  This will naturally give you `L>L0` for appropriate values of `c`..

Comment: @george2079 Yep, thanks.  Funny, I just figured this out.  I've been trying to track down why `DSolve` gives up after finding the general solution.  Similar to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63673), but that trick is not working.  It appears `Solve` gives up on a simple equation.... :(